# How is my disguised loadout determined if I disguise as a class that's not in play?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

Say RED has no sniper. I'm a BLU spy disguised as a RED sniper. This means my apparent nick will be determined at random. IIRC, I might even get my own nick.

What about my loadout? Will I be using weapons at random? Will it be taken from the appropriate loadout of the nick I'm using? Will I be using my own loadout?

Say I switch to the pistol and press B (use last disguise) and I get a sniper rifle. If I switched to the knife, pressed B, then back to the pistol and pressed B, would I stand a chance of getting a more believable huntsman instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your name will always be someone on the enemy team if disguised as an enemy, or someone on your own team if you disguise as a Friendly disguise.  In the case of a class not in play, the name will be a random player on the enemy team for an enemy disguise or your own name for a friendly disguise.

Regardless of the team you disguise as, if there is no player of that class, you also get a random fake health bar.

Your loadout is the stock loadout for that class.  For example, as a Sniper, your items will appear to be Sniper Rifle (Gun), SMG (Sapper), and Kukri (Knife).

Even if someone changes to that class, your disguises weapons will not change until you change disguises away from, then back to, that class.

Comment: Whoops, I just noticed when reviewing some past answers that I forgot to mention that your health is random when disguising as a class if the target team has none of that class.